# Is it possible not to inherit from boost::operators, but still use it?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, boost, operators

According to [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) - proper usage of boost::operators is to derive from it:

```
class A : boost::operators<A>
{
public:
    bool operator < (const A&) const { return false; }
};
```

Now, I can use `>` and `<=` and `>=` because all of these operators can be implemented with `<`, see code snippet from boost:

```
template <class T, class B = operators_detail::empty_base<T> >
struct less_than_comparable1 : B
{
     friend bool operator>(const T& x, const T& y)  { return y < x; }
     friend bool operator<=(const T& x, const T& y) { return !static_cast<bool>(y < x); }
     friend bool operator>=(const T& x, const T& y) { return !static_cast<bool>(x < y); }
};
```

And finally `less_than_comparable1` is one of `boost::operators` base class.

**PROBLEM:**
But adding such inheritance is not always convenient. E.g. this inheritance means I have to add constructor(s) to some structs, otherwise all old code, such as `A{1}` stops compiling:

```
struct A : boost::operators<A>
{
    A() = default;
    A(int a, int b = 0) : a(a), b(b) {}
    int a;
    int b;
};
bool operator < (const A&, const A&);
```

I tried several ways: inner class, static members of `boost::operators<A>` but it seems that only inheritance works.

---

I accept an answer that shows the way how to use boost::operators without inheritance.
I can also accept an answer, that explains why this inheritance is needed.

---

Ok, let's simplify a little this example, why I need inheritance in this very example below to get `operator >` from `operator <`?

```
template <typename A>
struct GtOperator
{
    friend bool operator > (const A& l, const A& r)
    {
        return r < l;
    }
};

struct A : private GtOperator<A>
{
    bool operator < (const A&) const
    {
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    if (A{} > A{})
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Nothing else seems to work, e.g. this way does not work:

```
struct A
{
    GtOperator<A> dummy;

    bool operator < (const A&) const
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Either write it out by hand, or write a preprocessor macro.  (There are only six operators, and you have to write `operator >` anyway.  Writing `operator ==` can often be useful too.)

Comment: @MartinBonner `boost::operators` offers much more than these 3. I just like to know how use it w/o inheritance if possible. Or to know why inheritance is needed

Comment: @jaggedSpire There is no casting to child class in boost::operators. There are only friend operators like these from `less_than_comparable1` - no downcasting. That is why I am asking why inheritance needed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible not to inherit from `boost::operators`, but still use it?

No, basically. It's intended to be inherited from. The reason it works is because argument-dependent lookup will only look for friend functions and function templates in *associated classes* ([basic.lookup.argdep]/4) - which are going to be `A` and `A`'s base classes. If `boost::operators<A>` isn't a base class of `A`, its `friend` functions won't be found by name lookup.

Even with new aggregate initialization rules in C++17, `A{1,2}` would break because you'd have to write `A{{},1,2}`.

Your best bet is probably to write a macro that functions as a mixin that effectively accomplishes the same thing. So the ordering ones would be:

```
#define LESS_THAN_COMPARABLE(T) \
 friend bool operator>(const T& x, const T& y)  { return y < x; } \
 friend bool operator<=(const T& x, const T& y) { return !static_cast<bool>(y < x); } \
 friend bool operator>=(const T& x, const T& y) { return !static_cast<bool>(x < y); }

class A
{
public:
    bool operator < (const A&) const { return false; }
    LESS_THAN_COMPARABLE(A)
};
```

Yes, that kind of sucks. (Also these could be defined as non-member functions as well, just drop the `friend` and put the macro invocation outside of the class).

The other alternative, besides adding constructors and writing macros, is to hope that [`<=>`](http://wg21.link/p0515) comes to fruition and then wait a few years to be able to use it.

Comment: I suspected that I get such answer. But I still do not know why the inheritance is needed here? Why such construction does not work `struct A { bool operator<(A)const; using dummy=boosts::operator<A>;};`. In "classic"  CRTP there is downcast to template parameter class - in boost::operators there are only friend functions, not downcasting at all

Comment: @PiotrNycz Added that explanation.

Comment: Ok, I found in parallel to your answer this wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0777.pdf. So the answer is ADL works only for functions injected as friend to base classes - that is the trick.